# Plotting a bar graph in R with two character date columns

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe like so:

```
month year count
1    2020  2301
2    2020  2311
3    2020  2417
4    2020  2205
5    2020  2399
6    2020  2367
```

I want to convert the dataset to something like this where the date column is actually of date type:

```
date    count
1/2020  2301
2/2020  2311
3/2020  2417
4/2020  2205
5/2020  2399
6/2020  2367
```

and then plot in gggplot using date as x axis and count as y axis..
How can i do this in R?

Comment: month/year cannot be Date type as it requires Day as well.  You my instead create a Date class and then change the format in x-axis

Comment: Perhaps a work around would be just using the first day of the month? but i would want the plot to only show the month and year.

Answer (score 1):

With `lubridate`, we can convert to `Date` class with `ymd` after `paste`ing the 'year', 'month' and using `truncated`.  Then, change the format in x axis

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(date = ymd(str_c(year, "/", month), truncated = 1)) %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x = date, y = count)) +
    geom_col()+
    scale_x_date(labels = date_format('%m/%Y'))
```

Comment: This is great. Do you know how I can plot a solid vertical line on 4/2020? How does this work when the x-axis are dates?

Comment: @Eisen you can use `geom_vline`